# Deshabilitar click, pero habilitar scroll en un div

Tags: html, css

Estoy usando:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print,screen">
    #aviso {
        pointer-events:none;
    }
</style>
```

para negar la opción de hacer click dentro de ese div, pero quiero poder hacer scroll dentro de él, lo cual no me permite hacer

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pordías estilar un elemento padre ya que [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) solo aplica al elemento actual pero el evento como tal **sí hace burbuja** por lo que no afecta al scroll y demás eventos de sus elementos padres.

Asumo que tienes algo como esto

```css
#aviso {
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#child {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="aviso">
  <div id="child">
    Contenido
  </div>
</div>
```

Efectivamente el scroll no funciona. Este es un ejemplo de como lo podrías hacer sin necesidad de usar javascript y el scroll ya funciona de nuevo

```css
#aviso {
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
#child {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 250px;
}
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="aviso">
    <div id="child">
      Contenido
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una opción con jQuery:

```
$('#aviso').click(false);
```

Otra opción sería con [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

```
$('#aviso').unbind('click');
```

Otra opción con javascript, aunque es más un truco que deshabilitar el clic:

```
document.getElementById("aviso").onclick = function(){return false;}
```